# Discord js bot hosted with heroku "Error: Cannot find module './rest/RESTManager'"

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, discord.js

im trying to host a discord bot with Heroku.
The bot works perfectly if i start it in my computer, but when i upload it to heroku it crashes.
This is the console output:

```
2020-06-17T13:06:28.372931+00:00 app[worker.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
2020-06-17T13:06:28.372939+00:00 app[worker.1]:     throw err;
2020-06-17T13:06:28.372940+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ^
2020-06-17T13:06:28.372940+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2020-06-17T13:06:28.372941+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Cannot find module './rest/RESTManager'
2020-06-17T13:06:28.372963+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
2020-06-17T13:06:28.372964+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
2020-06-17T13:06:28.372964+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
2020-06-17T13:06:28.372965+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2020-06-17T13:06:28.372965+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:5:21)
2020-06-17T13:06:28.372966+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
2020-06-17T13:06:28.372966+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
2020-06-17T13:06:28.372967+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2020-06-17T13:06:28.372967+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
2020-06-17T13:06:28.372968+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
2020-06-17T13:06:28.397002+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-06-17T13:06:28.397365+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
```

I have looked for the module rest or rest manager but i didnt find any module.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling discord.js? The problem seems to be with the discord.js module itself.

Comment: @ComputerGeek12 now the output have changed but still crashing.
Instead of './rest/RESTManager', now its requesting './BitField'